# How can I use Python multiprocessing to speed up the excel reading file?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am kinda new to Python and multiprocessing. I've been trying to write a program that will combine excel files into one. I want to use multiprocessing to read all the files so I can combine them later. I've tried different approaches but none worked. Any recommendations are welcome. Thank you!

Here is my full code with no multiprocessing:

```
from concurrent.futures import process
import os
import queue
import time
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

#convert CSV to excel
read_csv = pd.read_csv('Data\SampleCollectionID.csv')
excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Data\converted_CSV_file.xlsx')
read_csv.to_excel(excel_writer, index=False)
excel_writer.save()


#Combining the files
filenames = ['Data/converted_CSV_file.xlsx', 'Data/LabData.xlsx']
frame = pd.DataFrame()
for i in filenames: 
   df = pd.read_excel(i)
   df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()].copy()
   frame = pd.concat([frame, df], axis=1)
frame.to_excel('combinedData.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: how big are your dataframes? where is the bottleneck? 

I would also suggest just creating a list of dataframes and then concat at the end.

Comment: When you parallelize with multiprocessing, you have to include the cost of getting the data into one process for the concatenation and its usually just not worth it. You could have some success with multithreading - a couple of threads would would overlap one thread's read file with another thread's conversion. But only a little advantage. Both will end up waiting for the data from disk most of the time.

Comment: The data frames are not very big, around 600 rows and 10 columns (2 data frames). I am unsure where I could apply the multiprocessing on the code I currently have. The code is just for practicing multiprocessing

Comment: @JoãoPimenta if you are just practicing, I would skip `joblib` and start with just  `multiprocessing.Process`, and `multiprocessing.Queue`. You can get a lot done with those two things, and it will leave you with a better understanding. `joblib` is built on-top of `multiprocessing` to provide pre-written convenience functions, but it is still often important to know the nuances of parallel processing which you can learn using the base library

Comment: For a starting point, try to follow this procedure: create a function that takes in 2 queues: one for reading in file names to process, and one for writing out data from the file back to the main process. Then inside an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block (look it up...) create a number of processes targeted to that function. Feed the files you want to process into the input queue, and then start reading results from the output queue. At the end make sure the processes know they should quit (I usually send them `None` rather than a file name), and make sure they all quit using `join`

Comment: What you have there is an inherently serial process -- you cannot start on file #3 until you have finished with file #2.  Thus, your task in not suited for multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge and the code below worked nicely for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

files = glob.glob(my_path"\*.xlsx")

def loop(file_number):
    return pd.read_excel(file)

df = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)(delayed(loop)(file) for file in files)
df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```

This piece of code was adapted from this excellent post: https://towardsdatascience.com/read-excel-files-with-python-1000x-faster-407d07ad0ed8